# What is the password to this file? I can't figure it out with radare2 or gdb

Tags: disassembly, x86, decompilation

Here is the binary file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywN60yZYIhPPRyZMGbQudZRYoLYBhkeJ/view?usp=sharing

I am able to figure out some of the assembly, but can't get the correct password. I know that it is two integers separated by a space.

EDIT: By using the command `ps @ str.d__d` you get the result of `%d %d`. It is located at the address `0x0804853f`.

EDIT2: I figured out that there are multiple local variables being used:

```
var int local_2ch @ ebp-0x2c 
var int local_20h @ ebp-0x20 
var int local_1ch @ ebp-0x1c 
var unsigned int local_18h @ ebp-0x18 
var int local_14h @ ebp-0x14 
var int local_10h @ ebp-0x10
var int canary @ ebp-0xc
var int local_4h @ ebp-0x4 
arg int arg_4h @ esp+0x4
```

Comment: how do you know that it's "two integers separated by a space"? what else did you figure out?

Comment: By using the command `ps @ str.d__d` you get the result of `%d %d`.  This is all located at the address 0x0804853f.

Comment: please add what you already discovered to the question (click 'edit')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it. 
Usual stuff : `r2 file; aaa; pdf@sym.main`

You can see the params to `scanf` pushed to stack.

```
|           0x08048537      8d45e4         lea eax, [local_1ch]
|           0x0804853a      50             push eax
|           0x0804853b      8d45e0         lea eax, [local_20h]
|           0x0804853e      50             push eax
|           0x0804853f      6855860408     push str.d__d               ; 0x8048655 ; "%d %d" ; const char *format
|           0x08048544      e887feffff     call sym.imp.__isoc99_scanf ; int scanf(const char *format)
```

Lets rename locals.

```
[0x080484eb]> afv?
Usage: afv  [rbs]
| afvr[?]                       manipulate register based arguments
| afvb[?]                       manipulate bp based arguments/locals
| afvs[?]                       manipulate sp based arguments/locals
| afv*                          output r2 command to add args/locals to flagspace
| afvR [varname]                list addresses where vars are accessed (READ)
| afvW [varname]                list addresses where vars are accessed (WRITE)
| afva                          analyze function arguments/locals
| afvd name                     output r2 command for displaying the value of args/locals in the debugger
| afvn [new_name] ([old_name])  rename argument/local
| afvt [name] [new_type]        change type for given argument/local
| afv-([name])                  remove all or given var

[0x080484eb]> afvn input_1 local_20h
[0x080484eb]> afvn input_2 local_1ch
[0x080484eb]> pdf@sym.main
```

Now it looks like

```
|           0x08048537      8d45e4         lea eax, [input_2]
|           0x0804853a      50             push eax
|           0x0804853b      8d45e0         lea eax, [input_1]
|           0x0804853e      50             push eax
|           0x0804853f      6855860408     push str.d__d               ; 0x8048655 ; "%d %d" ; const char *format
|           0x08048544      e887feffff     call sym.imp.__isoc99_scanf ; int scanf(const char *format)
```

There's a check for Correct/Incorrect

```
|       `-> 0x08048579      837de800       cmp dword [local_18h], 0
|       ,=< 0x0804857d      7412           je 0x8048591
|       |   0x0804857f      83ec0c         sub esp, 0xc
|       |   0x08048582      685b860408     push str.Correct            ; 0x804865b ; "Correct!" ; const char *s
|       |   0x08048587      e824feffff     call sym.imp.puts           ; int puts(const char *s)
|       |   0x0804858c      83c410         add esp, 0x10
|      ,==< 0x0804858f      eb10           jmp 0x80485a1
|      ||   ; CODE XREF from main (0x804857d)
|      |`-> 0x08048591      83ec0c         sub esp, 0xc
|      |    0x08048594      6864860408     push str.Incorrect          ; 0x8048664 ; "Incorrect!" ; const char *s
|      |    0x08048599      e812feffff     call sym.imp.puts           ; int puts(const char *s)
|      |    0x0804859e      83c410         add esp, 0x10
```

If `local_18h` is 1/0, Correct/Incorrect is printed out to stdout respectively. Rename `local_18h` to `final_flag` as it decides the final output.

```
[0x0804852b]> afvn final_flag local_18h
```

Some constants are loaded to local variables. Remember/rename them to follow in code.

```
|           0x0804850f      c745e8010000.  mov dword [final_flag], 1
|           0x08048516      c745ec2a0000.  mov dword [local_14h], 0x2a ; '*' ; 42
|           0x0804851d      c745f0390500.  mov dword [local_10h], 0x539 ; 1337
```

`final_flag` is initially 1 (true). Just after input, there's a check to set `final_flag` to 0(false).

```
|           0x0804854c      8b45ec         mov eax, dword [const_2a]
|           0x0804854f      35280a0000     xor eax, 0xa28
|           0x08048554      89c2           mov edx, eax
|           0x08048556      8b45e0         mov eax, dword [input_1]
|           0x08048559      39c2           cmp edx, eax
|       ,=< 0x0804855b      7407           je 0x8048564
|       |   0x0804855d      c745e8000000.  mov dword [final_flag], 0
|       |   ; CODE XREF from main (0x804855b)
```

This can be roughly translated to:

```
if const_2a^0xa28 != input_1:
    final_flag = False
```

To pass this input_1 = const_2a^0xa28

```
>>> 0x2a^0xa28
2562
```

Similar check for input_2

```
|       `-> 0x08048564      8b45f0         mov eax, dword [const_539]
|           0x08048567      f7d0           not eax
|           0x08048569      89c2           mov edx, eax
|           0x0804856b      8b45e4         mov eax, dword [input_2]
|           0x0804856e      39c2           cmp edx, eax
|       ,=< 0x08048570      7407           je 0x8048579
|       |   0x08048572      c745e8000000.  mov dword [final_flag], 0
```

This can be roughly translated to:

```
if ~const_539 != input_2:
    final_flag = False
```

To pass this input_2 = ~const_539

```
>>> ~0x539
-1338
```

Finally

```
./part2
Enter the password: 2562 -1338
Correct!
```